# Usage about Pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I thought these two function were the same, but it seems that I was wrong.
I define two function f and g in this way:

```
let rec f n k =
   match k with
   |_ when (k < 0) || (k > n) -> 0
   |_ when k = n -> 100
   |_ -> (f n (k+1)) + 1

let rec g n k =
   match k with
   |_ when (k < 0) || (k > n) -> 0
   | n -> 100
   |_ -> (g n (k+1)) + 1

let x = f 10 5
let y = g 10 5
```

The results are:

```
val x : int = 105
val y : int = 100
```

Could anyone tell me what's the difference between these two functions?

---

**EDIT**

Why does it work here?

```
let f x =
   match x with
   | 1 -> 100
   | 2 -> 200
   |_ -> -1

List.map f [-1..3]
```

and we get

```
val f : x:int -> int
val it : int list = [-1; -1; 100; 200; -1]
```

Comment: the first has "when k = n" which is conditional whereas the second function doesn't have that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that

```
match k with 
... 
when k = n -> 100
```

is a case that matches when some particular condition is true (`k = n`).  The `n` used in the condition refers to the `n` that is bound as the function parameter.  On the other hand

```
match k with 
...
n -> 100
```

is a case that only needs to match `k` against a pattern variable `n`, which can always succeed.  The `n` in the pattern isn't the same `n` as the `n` passed into the function.

For comparison, try the code

```
let rec g n k =
   match k with
   |_ when (k < 0) || (k > n) -> 0
   | n -> n
   |_ -> (g n (k+1)) + 1
```

and you should see that when you get to the second case, the value returned is the value of the pattern variable `n`, which has been bound to the value of `k`.

This behavior is described in the Variable Patterns section of the [MSDN F# Language Reference, Pattern Matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx):

> #### Variable Patterns
>
> The variable pattern assigns the value being matched to a variable
>   name, which is then available for use in the execution expression to
>   the right of the **`->`** symbol. A variable pattern alone matches any
>   input, but variable patterns often appear within other patterns,
>   therefore enabling more complex structures such as tuples and arrays
>   to be decomposed into variables. The following example demonstrates a
>   variable pattern within a tuple pattern.
>
> ```
> let function1 x =
>     match x with
>     | (var1, var2) when var1 > var2 -> printfn "%d is greater than %d" var1 var2 
>     | (var1, var2) when var1 < var2 -> printfn "%d is less than %d" var1 var2
>     | (var1, var2) -> printfn "%d equals %d" var1 var2
>
> function1 (1,2)
> function1 (2, 1)
> function1 (0, 0)
> ```

The use of `when` is described in more depth in [Match Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The first function is ok, it calls recursively itself `n-k` times and returns 100 when matches with the conditional `where k = n`. So, it returns all the calls adding 1 `n-k` times. with your example, with `n=10` and `k=5` it is ok the result had been 105.

The problem is the second function. I tested [here](http://ideone.com/wRisCX). See I changed the pattern `n->100` to `z->100` and it still matches there and never calls itself recursively. So, it always returns 100 if it does not fail in the first conditional. I think F# don't allow that kind of match so it is better to put a conditional to get what you want.

Comment: I don't get it.. In function g, does it really assign 100 to n?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, I thought it was a general question about pattern-matching but it is related to F# (I recommend you to put language tag in your questions). I edited my question, I hope it helps this time.